# Man Bites Dog: symbol resolved *without* linking library? clock_gettime() -lrt

Tags: c++, clang, dynamic-linking

I have a C++ source tree developed under Ubuntu 12.04 using clang++ 3.2 that builds some libraries, then compiles some applications with these libraries and the usual collection of other various system libraries. Two puzzles. Client reports that code fails to build with undefined reference to clock_gettime(). Sure enough, I did not include the obligatory "-lrt" in the build logic (scons).

First puzzle: This compiles, links and executes correctly and without complaint on my system even though I do not specify "-lrt" *anywhere*! How does this symbol get correctly resolved? I suspect it is because the application links against a dynamic library that itself requires librt but I don't understand the logic behind why this would happen?

Second puzzle: Assuming a satisfactory explanation of how clock_gettime() gets resolved without "-lrt", why would this happen on my system but not on client's very similar setup?

"... a riddle, wrapped in a mystery, inside an enigma"   --- Winston Churchill

Suggestions for tools to reveal what is really going on here would be most welcomed.

Comment: It's maybe the particular version/fork/branch of GCC on one system that is nitpicky about the user linking against 1337 libraries even for standard library functions. IMHO the normal/acceptable behavior for a compiler is to automatically make available all the libraries which are needed to be linked against when using headers and functions in the C standard library. If a compiler doesn't do this, it's crap.

Comment: @H2CO3: That sounds like the `#pragma lib` solution, which is still unique to MSVC I think. BTW `clock_gettime` isn't a standard C function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From SUSv4 (Utilities/c99):

---

**`-l rt`**

This option shall make available all interfaces referenced in `<aio.h>`, `<mqueue.h>`, `<sched.h>`, `<semaphore.h>`, and `<spawn.h>`, interfaces marked as optional in `<sys/mman.h>`, interfaces marked as ADV (Advisory Information) in `<fcntl.h>`, and interfaces beginning with the prefix `clock_` and `time_` in `<time.h>`. *An implementation may search this library in the absence of this option.*

---

I presume the above suffices to at least justify why this behavior is allowed by POSIX.

Most likely the involved systems are different in this regard. For example, `clock_gettime()` might be implemented in `libc` for you, but in `librt` for your client. Don't take chances: use a portable `-l rt` and forget about the issue.

A more obvious example is `-l xnet`, which behaves similarly according to POSIX, but, at least on Gentoo, Debian and Ubuntu Linux systems, compiling with `-l xnet` actually yields an error. (`libxnet` purportedly contains the implementation for the UNIX sockets interface.)

If you want to further investigate the issue, try `ldd` in GNU/Linux systems. `ldd` should display the dynamic dependencies for your binary. I'd bet that `clock_gettime()` is simply implemented in `libc.so`.